# SQL delete all id paths of a model table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite3-ruby

Just deleted my all my model tables by (Setting.delete_all). But when I create a new setting it starts from id 12. How do i delete the ids of the "deleted settings"? I want to delete everything so that I start from setting/1 when I create a new setting.

Help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to drop your table and then regenerate it using migration:

To drop table:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION="20130910082232"    #replace with version no. of your table migration
```

Then create it again:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION="20130910082232"      #replace with version no. of your table migration
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for :) Have a lovely day!